# How to search some text in an array and get the index of the searched array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, filter

I want to get the index of filtered array

```js
const arr = ['apple', 'mango', 'orange', 'banana'];

const customFilter = (arr, searchtxt) => {
  const result = [];
  arr.filter(fruit => fruit.match(searchtxt)).forEach((element, index) => {
    result.push(index);
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(customFilter(arr, 'ma'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the index in the filtered array, not its index in the original array.

Don't use `filter()` for this. Just use `forEach()`, pushing the index into the result.

```js
const arr = ['apple', 'mango', 'orange', 'banana'];

const customFilter = (arr, searchtxt) => {
  const result = [];
  arr.forEach((fruit, index) => {
    if (fruit.match(searchtxt)) {
      result.push(index);
    }
  })
  return result;
}

console.log(customFilter(arr, 'ma'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`. For each item in the input, the code below adds its index to an array if it matches the given string.

```js
const arr = ['apple', 'mango', 'orange', 'banana'];

const customFilter = (arr, searchtxt) => {
  return arr.reduce((a, c, i) => c.match(searchtxt) ? [...a, i] : a, [])
}

console.log(customFilter(arr, 'ma'));
```